# Render Prawn pdf and rqrcode display QR with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, qr-code, prawn

Creating Ruby on rails web application with qrcode display QR code in pdf

Iam using

```
gem 'rqrcode-with-patches', require: 'rqrcode'
gem 'prawn'
```

My post Controller to show pdf view

```
def show
 @qr=RQRCode::QRCode.new(request.url)
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    pdf = PostPdf.new(@post)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "post#{@post.id}.pdf",
                          type: "application/pdf",
                          disposition: "inline"
   end
 end
end
```

**post_pdf**

```
class PostPdf < Prawn::Document
 def initialize(post)
  super({top_margin: 30, page_size: 'A4', page_layout: :landscape })
  @post = post
  post_id
  post_title
  qr_code
 end

 def post_id
  move_down 10
  text "Post id: #{@post.id}"
 end

 def post_title
  move_down 10
  text "Post title: #{@post.title}"
 end

 def qr_code
  move_down 10
  @qr=RQRCode::QRCode.new(request.url)
 end
end
```

i got error on display pdf, it's show

> > undefined local variable or method `request' for #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem called [prawn-qrcodes](https://github.com/gioele/prawn-qrcodes)  its really single to use.

```
require 'prawn/qrcodes'

Prawn::Document.generate("qr-big.pdf") do
    msg = "Hello world, this is a QR code"
    text msg

    qrcode msg, :position => :center,
                :fit => [bounds.height, bounds.width]
end
```

I think that this will work better for you than ** rqrcode-with-patches** because it was build for **prawn**